# How to fix issue of showing letters while writing on a textarea on Android OS?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I'm working on a .Net project for PhoneGap using jQuery mobile. I have a form containing text boxes and at the end of a page there is a text area:

```
<table width="100%" style="border-spacing: 4px;" class="tdContactUSLabel">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 25%">
                Sender
            </td>
            <td style="width: 75%">
                <input type="text" name="txtSender" id="txtComplaintPreUserFullName"  value="" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Email
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="email" name="txtemail" id="txtemail" value="" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                Message
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea name="txtMessage" id="txtMessage" class="textarea2" rows="8"
                    cols="15"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When i click on that text area the keypad opened and while I'm writing no letters appear in the text area until I dismiss the keypad. After dismissing the keypad all letters that I typed appear suddenly. Any one have idea why this happens?

By the way this issue only happens on devices that run Android OS.